# What causes node.js to wait until the request finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I wasted a bunch of time writing some code like this:

```
function processResponse(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.error(util.inspect(response, false, null));
    }
    waiting = false;
};

request.get(requestOpts.url, processResponse);

console.log("Waiting");
while(waiting) {
    count += 1;
    if(count % 10000000 == 0) {
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

I was trying to get node to wait (and not exit) until the reponse came back from the webserver.  Turns out, this didint' work, and what did work was doing nothing.  Just:

```
request.get(requestOpts.url, processResponse);
```

How did request keep node from exiting while the callback was pending?

Comment: The asynchronous primitive that `request` uses (in the `http` module?) does tell node not to exit while there's a callback waiting for a result.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this primitive?

Comment: It's native. It's implemented in the internals of the node platform. It talks to the event loop directly. There's not much more about it to say.

Comment: Google "event loop". Javascript is one of the two languages I know of with an event loop at its heart. The other is Tcl.

Comment: I might be horribly wrong but: that (endless) loop will block the event loop from processing received data and since it's stuck in that loop no data can be read from the socket and thus not be handled.

Comment: Just a note, if you're running tests and you want to force Node to exit, you can use the method: process.exit(0); to end your application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Node always keep track of any pending callbacks and will not exit until that hits zero. This will include all active network connections/requests as well as filesystem IO and subprocess activity. There's nothing special you need to code to get the expected behavior. node will do what you expect in this case by default.

Comment: How does it keep track of pending callbacks?

Comment: It keeps them in an internal data structure. I don't know the exact details but probably some flavor of priority queue.

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR**

In the code from the OP, the synchronous while-loop **prevents the event loop from ever reaching the poll phase**, so the event loop gets stuck on its first tick and the network I/O is never processed.

**Complete answer**

Node.js's asynchronous programming model is based on a synchronous loop called the **event loop**. The basic abstraction of the event loop is **function scheduling**: a function in Node.js is able to schedule other functions (like network request handlers and timers) to run *at some point in the future* and *in response to some event*.

The event loop is basically a continuously running "while loop". During each "tick" of the loop, the Node.js runtime checks to see whether the condition for a scheduled function is met -- if the condition is met (like if a timer has elapsed), the function is executed.

The event loop processes callbacks in a [particular order](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#event-loop-explained).

```
   ┌───────────────────────────┐
┌─>│           timers          │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│  │     pending callbacks     │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│  │       idle, prepare       │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
│  │           poll            │<─────┤  connections, │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      └───────────────┘
│  │           check           │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
└──┤      close callbacks      │
   └───────────────────────────┘
```

The only place for network requests to be processed is during the **poll phase**; so in order for a network request to be processed by a callback, **the event loop must reach the poll phase**.

Each stage of the event loop is only able to advance after the synchronous functions from the previous stage **have finished running** -- i.e. they have returned, and the call stack is empty.

In the code from the OP, the synchronous while-loop **prevents the event loop from ever reaching the poll phase**, so the network request handler is never executed.

**Looping while waiting on a network request**

In order to run code in a loop while we wait on the network request, we need to somehow give the event loop an opportunity to process other callbacks.

We can achieve this by running our loop in a callback scheduled via `setTimeout()`. `setTimeout()` is a mechanism for scheduling functions to run during the `timers` phase of the event loop.

Each time our loop finishes, the event loop has an opportunity to process new I/O events. If there's no new I/O event, it will move on to the next `setTimeout()` handler scheduled via `loop()`.

```
const request = require('request')

let count = 0
let isFinished = false

request.get('https://www.google.com', (err, res) => (isFinished = true))

console.log('Waiting')
loop()

function loop () {
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      count += 1
      if (isFinished) {
        console.log('done')
        return
      }

      if(count % 10 == 0) {
          console.log(count);
      }

      return loop()
    },
    0
  )
}
```

In this example, we keep "recursively" calling `loop` until the network request has finished. Each time the `setTimeout()` handler (scheduled by `loop()`) returns, the event loop moves beyond the `timers` phase and checks for new network I/O (i.e. our request to Google). As soon as the response is ready, our network request handler is called during the `poll` phase.

Even though `loop()` is "recursive", it doesn't increase the size of the call stack. Since each loop iteration is scheduled via `setTimeout`, the `loop()` function won't push another `loop()` call onto the call stack until the `setTimeout()` handler is run in the next `timers` phase - at which point the call stack from the previous `loop()` call will already be cleared.

Answer (score 2):

This code should be enough:

```
function processResponse(error, response, body) {
    console.log("Request complete");
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.error(util.inspect(response, false, null));
    }
};

console.log("Sending a request");
// Just as a test, try passing the URL hardcoded here,
// because your problem might be just a invalid requestOpts object
request.get("http://stackoverflow.com", processResponse);
```

One thing that is totally wrong with your previous code is the fact that loop is actually preventing the request to be executed. Node.js has a single event loop thread, and that code is just consuming 100% CPU, not giving room to your request to be executed.

However, it that code above does not work as expected, it might be related to the request library that you are using. If you are using `request-promise` instead of `request`, you need to use a different syntax.